# Catch number of user clicks in timespan using RxJava

Tags: android, buffer, rx-java, rx-android

I have application, which have hidden debug menu. I need to enable this secret menu, if (`Build.DEBUG` and) user clicks on a view for example 4x times in one second.
I would like to use for this RxJava.

I tried DebouncedBuffer by Kaushik Gopal on [weddingpartyapp](http://nerds.weddingpartyapp.com/tech/2015/01/05/debouncedbuffer-used-in-rxbus-example/), but this counts clicks, and returns value if there were no click over a specified period of time.

I have achieved the desired effect by using simple `buffer()`, but it starts buffering and keeps emitting empty lists, if there is no clicks. I can add `filter()`, but I would like to achieve same result different way.

I would like to start buffer after first click, and collect all clicks (`bufer()`?) with provided period of time (`debounce()`?), then stop buffering. I found `buffer(bufferOpenings, bufferClosingSelector)` [image]

which do what I need, and I found example of use, in [Intro-To-RxJava](https://github.com/Froussios/Intro-To-RxJava/blob/master/Part%203%20-%20Taming%20the%20sequence/5.%20Time-shifted%20sequences.md#buffer-by-signal)
but it depends in `interval()`. How to change, this, that first observable will be first value in group, and than function will triggered after one second from first value?

Moreover, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33779886/1888738), which adds checking number of items (which would be helpful too, cause I can stop `Observable` after receiving 4 clicks), but can I achieve same effect without creating new `Operator`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `buffer` you found is a good start but you also need `publish` to split the stream into two: one will be buffered to see if there is 4 clicks and the other will act as the trigger for for opening buffers with a time limit:

```
PublishSubject<Integer> source = PublishSubject.create();
TestScheduler ts = Schedulers.test();

source.publish(p -> 
    p.buffer(p, o -> Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, ts))
)
.filter(v -> v.size() == 4)
.subscribe(v -> System.out.println("Secret menu"));

System.out.println("Should open secret menu:");

source.onNext(1);
ts.advanceTimeBy(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
source.onNext(1);
ts.advanceTimeBy(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
source.onNext(1);
ts.advanceTimeBy(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
source.onNext(1);
ts.advanceTimeBy(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);


System.out.println("Should not open anything:");

source.onNext(1);
ts.advanceTimeBy(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
source.onNext(1);
source.onNext(1);
ts.advanceTimeBy(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
source.onNext(1);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I looking for. But can I switch 'p' Observable to RxView.clicks() in chain? Now I have one Observable 'RxView.clicks(button), which triggers 'source' PublishSubject 'onNext'

Comment: Just use `RxView.clicks(button).publish(...)` directly and don't replace the ... part above.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way I found to do this:

```
fun <T> Observable<T>.debounceWithEvents(time:Long,timeUnit: TimeUnit) = takeUntil(debounce(time, timeUnit))
```

It will return an observable that emits all events until the first one is debounced.
Hope this helps :)